# Unable to install VST0 Excel addin for all users in Excel 2007

Tags: c#, excel, deployment, wix, excel-addins

I developed a Wix Setup to install Excel addin for all users. I want to install VSTO Excel addin for Excel 2007,2010 and 2013 for all users. But I am able to install it in only Excel 2010 for all users
I am not able to install in Excel 2007 and 2013 for all users. I am using following registry components. Am I missing anything?

```
  <Component Id="Registry_FriendlyName">
      <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_FriendlyName" Root="HKLM"
                     Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\AddIn"
                     Name="FriendlyName"
                     Value="Add In"
                     Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="Registry_Description">
      <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_Description" Root="HKLM"
                     Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\AddIn"
                     Name="Description"
                     Value="Excel Add-In"
                     Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="Registry_Manifest">
      <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_Manifest" Root="HKLM"
                     Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\AddIn"
                     Name="Manifest" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]AddIn.vsto|vstolocal"
                     Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="Registry_LoadBehavior">
      <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_LoadBehavior" Root="HKLM"
                     Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\AddIn"
                     Name="LoadBehavior" Value="3"
                     Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
```

Comment: what .net framework did you select when you created the vsto? I think .NET 4 targets 2010, for older Excel you need to downgrade to a lower .NET framework...

Comment: I am using .NET framework 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a VSTO question than a WiX question.

What specific version of Excel are you trying to install for? There I believe only 2007 SP3 and newer support addin's from the HKLM hive.  Prior to that they did not have support for HKLM addin's because of security issues.

Lastly, are you sure the addin loader itself is not disabled?  Sometimes if you fail to load your addin the addin loader itself will become disabled.  Make sure that is still enabled.

Also, after you install and are testing your addin, make sure you launch Excel from the command prompt and have the following environment variables set:

```
SET VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS=0
SET VSTO_LOGALERTS=1
```

This will make sure that Excel shows your loading errors during startup so you can debug what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar scenario at work but with a Word addin.

I found that for 2007, you need an additional registry entry to "enable" the vstolocal functionality as described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811

For reference (in case the URL is dead in the future):

> Apply hotfix package 976477 (Description of the 2007 Office system hotfix package (Mso-x-none.msp): October 27, 2009)
>   Enable the hotfix package. To do this, follow these steps:
>   In the registry, locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>
> ```
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\General\
>    On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
>    Type EnableLocalMachineVSTO, and then press ENTER.
>    Right-click EnableLocalMachineVSTO, and then click Modify.
>    In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
>    Exit Registry Editor.
> ```

I replaced the "\Office\" in the registry path with "\Word\", so you may find success using "\Excel\" if it doesn't work as described on that URL.

Edit: For info, I believe the Hotfix that is mentioned on the URL above is already included in the latest Office 2007 service pack, so you probably won't need to install it separately.